# Script to delete all folders barring the last two most modified?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a recursive script to delete all folders in a subfolder named 'date-2012-01-01_12_30' but leave the two latest.

/var/www/temp/updates/ then hundreds of folders by 'date' and by 'code'

e.g.

```
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2012-01-_12_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2012-02-_13_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2013-11-_12_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp2/date-2012-01-_12_30
```

I was thinking about using a find to get the folder but unsure how to know what folders I can delete as the script will have to know how date - folders are in that subfolder and which ones are the latest ones

Hmm, any help would be great?

Code:

```
$PATH=/var/www/temp/updates/*/*
find $PATH -type d -name "date-*" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n -2 | cut -f2- | xargs ls -l
```

The script will need to go through thousands of different folders and keep the two most recent folders - Someone on here helped before but I haven't changed it for the thousands of folders to search through

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script for deleting old files in directory except latest N](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888508/script-for-deleting-old-files-in-directory-except-latest-n)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script

```
PATH1=/var/www/temp/updates
find $PATH1 -iname "date-*" -print0 | ls -tr | tail -2 | xargs -I file rm -fr file
```

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the script will work fine as the find will going through all the folders under /updates/

```
$PATH=/var/www/temp/updates/*/*
find $PATH -type d -name "date-*" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | xargs rm -rf
```